# Permutation property of "law of cosines" stated more compactly through abstract algebra

Tags: group-theory, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, permutation-cycles

The law of cosines, stated: $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - |a||b|\cos(\gamma)$ is a result that still holds if we swap the side-lengths and the corresponding angle.

Is there a way to capture this symmetry from a group-theoretic perspective? Or some other abstract algebraic perspective?

I apologize, I'm not entirely sure how to ask this due to significant lack of knowledge. I think one could use Galois theory to state this more elegantly -- by defining this to be a quadratic polynomial in some sense. Or we could not use Galois theory at all and think about a corresponding permutation group.

I'm also unaware if this is already a fairly common sidenote in the study of, say, quadratic forms for a particular geometry.

**Motivation:** Wherever I see this elementary result stated, either the other 2 corresponding equations are stated alongside it, or it's stated that the equation would still work if we swapped the variables. Having learned aspects of group theory and abstract algebra, I feel there is a better way to state this. And I'm hoping this more abstract way of interpreting this could lead to an elementary example of a more advanced concept -- and as a bonus, potentially open the door to better understanding applications of quadratic forms and of defining a geometry through a group-theoretic perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do here, but if you're familiar with $S_3$, the symmetric group on $3$ letters,  you could probably use that here.  Each element of $S_3$, there are $6$, would permute $a,b$ and $c$ (let's say the angle  $\gamma $ changes automatically), and give a different version.

The elements are $\{e,(ab),(ac),(bc),(abc),(acb)\}$.

So $e$ does nothing.

Take $(ab)$.  It just interchanges $a$ and $b$.  So $c^2=a^2+b^2-\mid a\mid\mid b\mid\cos(\gamma) $ becomes $c^2=b^2+a^2-\mid b\mid\mid a\mid\cos(\gamma) $, which is the same statement.

We expect $3$ of them to be repeats, right?   Because there are only $3$ cases of the law of cosines.

But look at what $(ac)$ does.  We get $a^2=c^2+b^2-\mid c\mid\mid b\mid\cos(\alpha)$, where of course $\alpha$ is the angle opposite side $a$.

What do you think?

If you want a compact way of saying it, you could probably get away with saying that you can "cyclically permute" $a,b$ and $c$ (but of course you have to remember to change the angle), to get the other cases.

Comment: Thank you. This is a formulation that captures the permutation invariance I was after. It also seems there is not an obvious way to go forward (as in, there isn't already work done on here that's widely popularized), so it makes sense to innovate if necessary.